# Labels are sometimes not shown on vaadin-custom-field that contains custom element

Tags: css, typescript, vaadin, vite

I'm experiencing this on Vaadin 24.x Flow project on Spring Boot.

I have a view that contains FormLayout like this:

```
<vaadin-form-layout id="feed-overview" class="osiris-card orisis-card-form">
    <vaadin-text-field colspan=1 id="network-field" label="Network" theme="readonly" readonly></vaadin-text-field>
    <vaadin-custom-field colspan=1 label="Address" has-label><address-link id="address-field"></address-link></vaadin-custom-field>
    <vaadin-custom-field colspan=1 label="Maintainer" has-label><address-link id="creator-field"></address-link></vaadin-custom-field>
    <vaadin-button colspan=1 label="Body" id="source-button" theme="primary contrast">View in Studio</vaadin-button>
    <vaadin-big-decimal-field colspan=1 class="important-text" id="security-field" label="Security Sum" theme="readonly" readonly></vaadin-big-decimal-field>
</vaadin-form-layout>
```

Both `vaadin-custom-field` contain custom element `address-link` described as:

```
import {LitElement, css, html} from 'lit';
import {customElement, property} from 'lit-element';
import { applyTheme } from 'Frontend/generated/theme';

@customElement('address-link')
export class AddressLink extends LitElement {

  protected override createRenderRoot() {
    const root = super.createRenderRoot();
    applyTheme(root);
    return root;
  }

    render() {
        return html`<vaadin-horizontal-layout clase="vaadin-field-container" part="address-layout" theme="spacing-s" style="width: 100%;">
                            <a href="${this.explorerLink}" part="scan-link" class="explorer-link" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
                                    ${this.shortName}
                            </a>
                            <vaadin-button class="copy" part="copy-button" theme="icon tertiary-inline" @click="${this.copyToClipboard}">
                                <vaadin-icon class="copy-icon" icon-class="fa fa-copy"></vaadin-icon>
                                <vaadin-tooltip slot="tooltip" text="Click to copy"></vaadin-tooltip>
                            </vaadin-button>
                        </vaadin-horizontal-layout>`;
    }
}
```

The problem is, I can see labels on `vaadin-custom-field` when I developing, but **when I deploy to production server**, CustomField labels are missing (I can see that there's no `<label>` tag in html). All other fields of the same FormLayout show labels as expected.

[image: Screen of page]

[image: HTML of page]

I tried to include custom-field inside address-link component (I thought it's some sort of issue with shadowDom, but to no avail.
I use no styles that affect labels somehow and I already tried all about dev-bundle settings/recreation/etc, so I don't think it's cache-related.
Labels are still not shown **on production server**.

Environment:

- Vaadin 24.1.x (tried update to 24.2 - no changes)
- Spring Boot 3.1.1
- Developing PC - Windows
- Deployment Server - Ubuntu 20
- I use bootJar

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the  component hasn't been loaded at all (since there is no shadow DOM inside the root element, so it's not just the label missing).

So maybe it's just missing from your imports?